# selenium Page factory handle different elements for same page for different users

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I have a simple question. I 'm sure many of us might have got into the same situation. I am using page object pattern. Below are the steps i do along the navigation.

1. Login to my application as one type of user.
2. Click some link to go form page.
3. On form page , fills the fields and submit
4. Logout

On 3) the form object page shows some different input fields depending on the type of the user, which i need to interact with. So how do i deal it within the same page object.  Has anybody got into the same situation and have found some decent way of doing this ?

Comment: There will be some types of customers, right ? For example, Gold privilege, Silver privilege, Bronze.... and so on .

Comment: yes , the users( or customers) belong to different groups which differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

I know it a simple automation script not a Java project where we should be using all oops concepts but still I would go with the following:

1. Create a parent page class containing the common WebElements and methods.
2. Create child classes with elements and methods specific to that customer.
3. In the test, pass a parameter which specifies the type of customer and call the appropriate child class.

If you don't want any of this inheritance stuff, you can also try the following.

1. Create a page class with elements for all types of customers.
2. Create  generic methods which can take a parameter customerType and perform operations like if customerType==1 do these operations else do these.

Another solution which popped up in my mind, assuming that all fields for a particular customer are mandatory, is as follows.

1. Create a common class for all elements.
2. Create a generic method in the page class which follows the condition, if this element is present then enter value.

Comment: I like the inheritance part better. But i've got an issue there. Let's say if there are 25 groups(or more in future) , i will end up writing 25 sub classes for each group which i'm afraid of ;). I was thinking if we could provide  elements locators dynamically for that particular page.

Comment: I dont know how providing dynamic values to element locators is possible. But I have added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the concept of Page object model then this questions will be more clear to you. Yes, inheritance is a big factor here. I suggest you read through [this](http://peternewhook.com/2010/09/automated-testing-pageobjects-webdriver/) to see how a real page object model should work. And, solution of #3 question is as simple as UI mapping. Something like

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "q")
private WebElement searchBox;
```

for each elements or similar implementation.

For a complete page object you should map all the `elements` **not depending on the users**. The reason being, every time you call that class it will be instantiated and all the mapped elements as well. There is no need of **dynamically load the elements** If any elements are not used or hidden on the page those will be available and you will not be using them anyway

Comment: I agree with you that when instantiating page objects it should not be dependant on the users but i think i probably need to still check it in my fillform function if the element is displayed or not , otherwise i will get element not found exception for the elements present for one user but not for another.

Comment: You have completely missed my point! Say user `manager` should see `filedA` and `fieldB` and user `employee` should see `fieldA` only. You will still need to map both `filedA` and `filedB`. If you log in as manager and use both fields you will not get any exception wheres logging in as `employee` if you try to access `filedA` you will get exception. You don't need any additional check here.